# Ruby/Mechanizeでのスクレイピングで対象の要素を絞り込む方法と複数のURLを処理する方法

Tags: ruby, mechanize

RubyでMechanizeを使用しでスクレイピングを行いたいです。

```
<div id="movie_photo">
 <a href="movie/83603/">
 <img alt="ポスター画像" src="画像のURL">
```

という構成のWEBサイトから、画像のURLを取得したいです。
問題が２つあります。
１つめが

```
require 'mechanize'

agent= Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://eiga.com/movie/83603/")
elements = page.search('a img')

elements.each do |ele|
  puts ele.get_attribute('src')
end
```

のように記述したら、そのWEBサイト内の他のa img　src　構造の欲しくないURLの情報も取ってきてしまいました。

２つめが
上記のコードでは１このWEBサイトから１このURLの情報も取って来るように記述しようとしていますが、`page = agent.get("http://eiga.com/movie/83603/")`で指定したURLの連番の/83604/,
/83605/,/83606/....の計２０個のa img　src　構造の欲しいURL情報も取りたいということです。
links=[]と記述するようですがどうコードを記述すればいいのかわかりません。

欲しいURL１個だけを取得して、連番のURLの２０個の欲しいURLも一遍に取得できるようなコードを書きたいです。

お願いいたします。

Comment: この内容であればrailsに限定した話ではないように思いますが、railsに限定した意図はなんでしょうか。

Comment: railsに限定した意図はないです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一つ目については`div#movie_phpto` (`<div id="movie_photo"></div>`に対するCSSセレクタ)を`#search`の条件に追加すれば良いでしょう。Mechanize(が内部で使っているNokogiri)はXPATHかCSSセレクタを使って要素を検索しますので、詳しいことはそれらのドキュメントを参照してください。
二つ目についてははURLが連番で増えていくことがわかっているのであればループを1段増やして数字を増やしていけばいいでしょう

```
(0..19).each do |i|
  page = agent.get("http://eiga.com/movie/#{83603 + i}/")
  elements = page.search('div#movie_photo a img')
  elements.each do |ele|
      puts ele.get_attribute('src')
  end
end
```